# Formula to select a date 3 business days later than the cell on its left

Tags: excel, date, time, formula, cell

In my Excel workbook, I have "November 10th". I want every cell in the column to the right to display a date 3 days later, but it has to be a weekday Monday - Friday, it can't fall on a Saturday or Sunday. So if "November 10th" is a Thursday the date on the cell next to it should state "November 14th".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the date in `A1`, use `=WORKDAY(A1,3)`.

You can also put the third argument to exclude holidays in this [function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33).